# How to create Invoice from Sales Orders using Workflows in NetSuite

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I have a plugin that creates a Sales Order in NetSuite using its API. Now I'm trying to create an invoice in NetSuite based on that Sales Order using a Workflow.

I tried creating a workflow that is supposed to trigger when a sales order is created.

In the actions to be performed after the record gets created, I chose transform record into an Invoice.

When I triggered the Sales Order creation through my plugin, I expected to see the record get transformed into an invoice. But, nothing happened. When I looked at the workflow trigger history, there was nothing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do the exact settings for your workflow look like?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your workflow's status is **Released**.
Make sure you have selected proper configuration under **Event Definition**, from your description you might want to check `On Create` and since you are not performing any operations on Sales Order, your **Trigger Type** should be `After Record Submit`. In **Contexts** select the correct context from which your Sales Order is being created like RESTlet, Suitelet etc.

For details on description you can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4080817850.html) out.